# Creating HTML from a DataTable using C#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, outlook

I need to be able to pass HTML data into Outlook like this:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.Body = myBody;
```

Initially, I thought I could pass plain text to it and use `PadLeft` like this:

```
somestring.PadLeft(100);
```

but it did not align everything properly because even though `|||||` and `MMMMM` are both only 5 characters in length, they physically on the screen take up more space.

My solution is to convert data that is in my datatable into an HTML table and then pass it into Outlook.

1. how do I convert a datatable into an html table?
2. is there a better solution to my issue?

Comment: Iterate over the Rows and Columns collections of the DataTable, and build up an html string from the individual cell values.

Comment: They take up different amounts of space because the font you are using is not monospaced.  Maybe a monospaced font is a solution.

Comment: @DJQuimby thanks so much!! what is an example of a monospace font?

Comment: @I__ Here's a list of some: http://www.lowing.org/fonts/

Comment: @DJQuimby please see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3288549/117700

Comment: @I__ Thanks for pointing that out to me, I had failed to consider that!

Comment: @DJQuimby can you help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793160/getting-the-innerhtml-of-an-htmltable-c-sharp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Loop over your DataTable, and build up the html string. IE:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("col1");
dt.Columns.Add("col2");
dt.Columns.Add("col3");
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "a", "b", "c" });
dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "d", "e", "f" });

string tab = "\t";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("<html>");
sb.AppendLine(tab + "<body>");
sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "<table>");

// headers.
sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");

foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{        
    sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", dc.ColumnName);        
}

sb.AppendLine("</tr>");

// data rows
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        string cellValue = dr[dc] != null ? dr[dc].ToString() : "";
        sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", cellValue);
    }

    sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
}

sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "</table>");
sb.AppendLine(tab + "</body>");
sb.AppendLine("</html>");
```

Comment: thanks so much! i'm sorry my HTML is not great. how would i wrap the tags in there?

Comment: I've updated the code snippet to show how to wrap it in the tags. See this url about using html tables: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: How could I add a border around the table using this code?

Answer (score 6):

I just want to share what I did. I hope this would help.

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

public void Build(DataSet ds) 
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables) 
    {
        //Create a table
        Table tbl = new Table();

        //Create column header row
        TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns) {
            TableHeaderCell th = new TableHeaderCell();
            th.Text = col.Caption;
            thr.Controls.Add(th);
        }
        tbl.Controls.Add(thr);

        //Create table rows
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            foreach (var value in row.ItemArray)
            {
                TableCell td= new TableCell();
                td.Text = value.ToString();
                tr.Controls.Add(td);
            }
            tbl.Controls.Add(tr);
        }

        tbl.RenderControl(w);

    }

    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Code could be pretty long to write here, I agree with @mservidio. Follow this link to see an example of what you have to do: [this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1093574.aspx/1)

Comment: Side note: check your data, if they aren't numbers they may contain invalid characters for HTML so a raw ToString() doesn't work ("<" for example).

Answer (score 3):

> how do i convert a datatable into an html table?

The only way is to write code that goes through every row and builds the HTML string the way you need it.

> is there a better solution to my issue?

You could use a monospace font (such as `Courier`) wihch will allow you to align everything properly by simply outputting the right number of spaces but you'd still need to send the email in HTML format setting the proper font on the document.

Answer (score 3):

```
public string ConvertDataTableToHTMLTableInOneLine(DataTable dt)
    {
        //Convert DataTable To HTML Table in one line
        return "<table>\n<tr>" + string.Join("", dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(dc => "<td>" + dc.ColumnName + "</td>")) + "</tr>\n" +
        "<tr>" + string.Join("</tr>\n<tr>", dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => "<td>" + string.Join("</td><td>", row.ItemArray) + "</td>").ToArray()) + "</tr>\n<\table>";

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to output the HTML.

If this is a relatively easy format (not much formatting, styles etc.) I would definitely go with @mservidio's suggestion.

If the output is more complex and you have experience with ASP.NET you can go the route of a UserControl which allows more flexibility and management of the output. You can then render the output of the control to HTML like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

ctrl.RenderControl(hw);
return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: If it is simple, I would go with the answer presented by @mservidio

Answer (score 0):

```
public string toHTML_Table(DataTable dt)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                return "";

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("<html>");
            builder.Append("<head>");
            builder.Append("<title>");
            builder.Append("Page-");
            builder.Append(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            builder.Append("</title>");
            builder.Append("</head>");
            builder.Append("<body>");
            builder.Append("<table border='1px' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' ");
            builder.Append("style='border: solid 1px Silver; font-size: x-small;'>");
            builder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");
            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {
                builder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'><b>");
                builder.Append(c.ColumnName);
                builder.Append("</b></td>");
            }
            builder.Append("</tr>");
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                builder.Append("<tr align='left' valign='top'>");
                foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
                {
                    builder.Append("<td align='left' valign='top'>");
                    builder.Append(r[c.ColumnName]);
                    builder.Append("</td>");
                }
                builder.Append("</tr>");
            }
            builder.Append("</table>");
            builder.Append("</body>");
            builder.Append("</html>");

            return builder.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version of it, with added the possibility to "highlight" some rows based on a generic rule (rowHighlightRule parameter).

```
  public static string ToHTML(this DataTable dt, Func<DataRow, bool> rowHiglithRule)
    {

        if (dt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("dt");

        string tab = "\t";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "<table>");

        // headers.
        sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<thead><tr>");

        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", dc.ColumnName);
        }

        sb.AppendLine("</thead></tr>");

        // data rows
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (rowHiglithRule != null)
            {

                if (rowHiglithRule(dr))
                {
                    sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr class=\"highlightedRow\">");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Non ho alcuna regola, quindi caso normale.
                sb.Append(tab + tab + tab + "<tr>");
            }

            foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                string cellValue = dr[dc] != null ? dr[dc].ToString() : "";
                sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", cellValue);
            }

            sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
        }

        sb.AppendLine(tab + tab + "</table>");


        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 public string MakeJPGFromDataTable(DataTable dt)
    {
        Font fnt = new System.Drawing.Font("verdana", 10,FontStyle.Bold);
        string strPath = Path.GetTempPath();
        string strJPG = "";
        strPath += "Publisher";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(strPath);
        Graphics grfx = CreateGraphics();
        float nWdBMP = 0;
        float nHtBMP = 0;

        var TalleststringLength = dt.AsEnumerable().Max(row => row.ItemArray.Max(x => grfx.MeasureString(x.ToString(), fnt).Height));
        var longeststringLength = dt.AsEnumerable().Max(row => row.ItemArray.Max(x => grfx.MeasureString(x.ToString(), fnt).Width));
        //string ss =  dt.Columns[1].ToString();
        //int[] nColHeaderLengths = (from z in new int[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } select dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Max(dc => (int)grfx.MeasureString(dt.Columns[z].ToString(), fnt).Width)).ToArray();
        //int[] nColWidths = (from z in new int[7] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } select dt.AsEnumerable().Max(row => (int)grfx.MeasureString(row.ItemArray[z].ToString(), fnt).Width)).ToArray();
        var xx = (from x in dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select x.Ordinal).ToArray();
        var nColWidths = (from z in (xx)
                           select dt.AsEnumerable().Max(row =>
                               (grfx.MeasureString(row.ItemArray[z].ToString(), fnt).Width >
                               grfx.MeasureString(dt.Columns[z].ToString(), fnt).Width)
                               ? grfx.MeasureString(row.ItemArray[z].ToString(), fnt).Width
                               : grfx.MeasureString(dt.Columns[z].ToString(), fnt).Width)
            ).ToArray();

        nWdBMP = nColWidths.Sum();
        nHtBMP = TalleststringLength * (dt.Rows.Count + 1);
        int xPos = 0;
        int yPos = 0;
        int nMargin = 10;

        Bitmap mapMem = new Bitmap((int)nWdBMP + (nMargin * (dt.Columns.Count + 1)), (int)nHtBMP);
        Graphics grfxMem = Graphics.FromImage(mapMem);
        grfxMem.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        grfxMem.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        grfxMem.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        grfxMem.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.GammaCorrected;

        grfxMem.FillRectangle(lgBackgroundBrush,0,0,mapMem.Width,mapMem.Height);

        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            grfxMem.DrawString(dt.Columns[j].ToString(), fnt, lgFontBrush, xPos, yPos);
            //xPos += (int)grfx.MeasureString(dt.Columns[j].ToString(), fnt).Width;
            xPos += (int)nColWidths[j] + nMargin;
        }
        xPos = 0;
        yPos += (int)TalleststringLength;
        grfxMem.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, yPos), new Point((int)mapMem.Width, yPos));
        //foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        //{
        //    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
        //    {
        //        grfxMem.DrawString(dr[j].ToString(), fnt, Brushes.Blue, xPos, yPos);
        //        xPos += (int)nColWidths[j] + nMargin;
        //    }
        //    xPos = 0;
        //    yPos += (int)TalleststringLength;
        //}
        int s = 0;
        Func<object, bool> too_much_where = delegate(object itemCurrent)
        {
            grfxMem.DrawString(itemCurrent.ToString(), fnt, lgFontBrush, xPos, yPos);
            xPos += (int)nColWidths[s++] + nMargin;
            if (s >= dt.Columns.Count)
            {
                //Know what this determines the end of every row
                s = 0;
                xPos = 0;
                yPos += (int)TalleststringLength;
                grfxMem.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, yPos), new Point((int)mapMem.Width, yPos));
            }
            return false;
        };
        //var sizzeler = (from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
        //                let drItems = (from itemCurrent in dr.ItemArray select itemCurrent)
        //                               from item in drItems
        //                                where too_much_where(item)
        //                    select new
        //                    {
        //                        z = true,
        //                    }
        //                ).ToArray();
        var sizzeler = (from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        where (dr.ItemArray.Where(itemCurrent => too_much_where(itemCurrent)).Count() == 0)
                        select new
                        {
                            z = true,
                        }
                        ).ToArray();
        s = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < nColWidths.Length; j ++)
        {
            grfxMem.DrawLine(pen, new Point(s, 0), new Point(s, (int)mapMem.Height));
            s += (int)(nColWidths[j] + nMargin );
        }
        s = mapMem.Width-1;
        grfxMem.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(0, 0, mapMem.Width - 1, mapMem.Height - 1));
        s = 0;
        grfx.DrawImage(mapMem, (float)10.0, (float)10.0);
        grfx.Dispose();
        return strJPG;
    }
```

Comment: He didin´t say JPG but HTML.