# Get Data from Data reader to Front End

Tags: c#, html, console-application, datareader

Following is my Console Application code to get data from SQL.

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=fcpcdb02; database=campus6; user id=; password=;"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from [Campus6].[dbo].[TRANSCRIPTDETAIL] where FINAL_GRADE='I' and ACADEMIC_YEAR = '2017'  and ACADEMIC_TERM='02TERM'";
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sqlRdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // table = new DataTable();  
                    // table.Load(reader);  
                    if (sqlRdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (sqlRdr.Read())
                        {
                            id = (sqlRdr["PEOPLE_CODE_ID"].ToString());
                            subname = (sqlRdr["EVENT_LONG_NAME"].ToString());
                            eventid = (sqlRdr["EVENT_ID"].ToString());

                            year1 = (sqlRdr["ACADEMIC_YEAR"].ToString());
                            term = (sqlRdr["ACADEMIC_TERM"].ToString());
                            session = (sqlRdr["ACADEMIC_SESSION"].ToString());
                            subtype = (sqlRdr["EVENT_SUB_TYPE"].ToString());
                            section = (sqlRdr["SECTION"].ToString());
                            orgcode = (sqlRdr["ORG_CODE_ID"].ToString());
                        }
```

And this is my code to Generate HTML file

```
TextWriter tw = File.CreateText(@"C:\Users\sganatra\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\incompletechange\files\" + year1 + "" + term + ".html");


                            string template = System.IO.File.ReadAllText((@"C:\Users\sganatra\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\incompletechange\files\changegrade.html"));

                            tw.WriteLine("" + template + "");
                            Console.WriteLine("Text created");
                            tw.Close();
                            Console.WriteLine(Console.Read());
```

Now want I am trying to do is get the value from the data reader and store it in html before downloading it. I goggled few options they work for .aspx files and i get data into it but when I download it converting it into html I cannot see any data.

Comment: Is this your minimal, complete, and verifiable code example? Any chance to improve your question by following this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: aspx already have the tags insert so they are html.  Straight text files do not have tags and you have to add the tags in your software.  See following posting for example of converting a datatable to html : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792882/creating-html-from-a-datatable-using-c-sharp

Comment: @QualityCatalyst I removed undesired code.

Comment: @jdweng I get the tags and table is also created but just i cannot see any data in it.

Comment: I don't see any code that creates the changegrade.html file.  I would check the data for the changegrade.html file and see if your code is actually generating this file.  The TextWriter tw looks like it is reading the changegrade.html file and just but then just adding double quotes at the beginning and end of file.  I

Comment: I don't see any code that creates the changegrade.html file.  I would check the data for the changegrade.html file and see if your code is actually generating this file.  The TextWriter tw looks like it is reading the changegrade.html file and just but then just adding double quotes at the beginning and end of file.  I'm not sure why the double quotes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to populate the template with placeholders, and once that template is loaded into your application you will need to use the `Replace(string, string)` method to fill in the blanks.

Please be aware that your query may return more than 1 record, and your *reader* routine is just going iterate through all of the records and your string variables are going to contain the last record's values. If this is the case, you may want to reconsider your general design. If you want to write out all of these records, the templating system would need to be within the `while(Read)' loop

In the following incomplete example, I am going to have the placeholders in my template surrounded with double pound signs (ie `##Placeholder##`).

```
// earlier code
string template = System.IO.File.ReadAllText((@"C:\Users\sganatra\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\incompletechange\files\changegrade.html"));

template.Replace("##id##", id);
template.Replace("## subname##",  subname);
template.Replace("##eventid##", eventid);
// and so on for year1 => orgcode

tw.WriteLine("" + template + "");
// and the rest of your code
```